# LIKE and NOT operatores - condition of a string that does not have a predetermined word

Tags: php, mysql

tab_names (fictional example)

```
id   name
3 - Fred
5 - Fred - Family
7 - Marie
9 - Marie - Family
```

In the following very specific situation, 'Fred' and 'Fred - Family' are the same entity.

I need to get 'Fred' id from 'Fred - Family' id.

I know it's strange ...

My idea to solve:

1- First I get the 'name' corresponding to id 8 (that is, 'Fred - Family');

2 - Then I query the database for the id of the row that corresponds to the value 'Fred - Family' minus the string '- Family'

Illustration:

```
$name_family  = 'Fred - Family';

SELECT name FROM tab_names WHERE name LIKE  \"$name_family\" 
AND name NOT LIKE  '% - Family'
```

Any ideas how to build this query?
Thanks.

Comment: You will always have to respect a pattern `Name1 - Name2` and will have to search for `Name1` ? Can you have more than 2 'Name'?

Comment: If you only want the `Fred` and if you will ALWAYS have ` - Family` after the name you want, you can 1/ Use `explode()` OR remove the ` - Family` part of your string, then just do `"SELECT...WHERE name = ".$yourSimpleName` no?

Comment: @MickaelLeger. Thanks. I edited the table example in my  post.If I understand correctly you suggest that I first edit the string 'Fred - Family' with php to remove the word '- Family'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove the '- Family' string directly in SQL.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tab_names 
WHERE 
name = (
   SELECT SUBSTRING(name, 1, LENGTH(name) - 9) 
   FROM tab_names 
   WHERE id = 8 LIMIT 1
)
```

Line `SUBSTRING(name, 1, LENGTH(name) - 9)` removes 9 characters from the end of the name

Comment: Thanks. I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: Works great Bogdans.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

If I follow your pattern, you can do something like this maybe :

**1/ Remove the '- Family' part :**

```
$name_family  = 'Fred - Family';
$name_family = explode('-', $name_family);
$name = trim($name_family[0]); //eg. Fred
```

OR

```
$name_family  = 'Fred - Family';
$name = str_replace(' - Family', '' ,$name_family); //eg. Fred
```

**2/ Then you just search in your table by exact family name :**

```
SELECT name FROM tab_names WHERE name = \"$name\"
```

You should only get the entity where name is `Fred` (so 'Fred - Family' won't be return).

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @Michael. Thanks. I'm trying on your suggestion.

Comment: @MIcahel. Works great.